# How to write linux grep, sed, diff sentences in a php file or in a perl file

Tags: php, perl, sed, grep, diff

I want to compare 2 text files using Diff, grep, and sed.

First, How to write linux grep, sed, diff sentences in a php file or in a perl file?

how to write this diff in php or perl:

```
$ diff C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt C:/Users/User/Desktop/text2.txt > C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt
```

how to write this sed in php or perl:

```
$ sed -i -r 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt
```

Second, What is better? writing it in PHP file or Perl file?
**I want to call this script from PHP file.**

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**
I try this:

```
$text_files_path = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/dbs"; 
$command = ("diff $text_files_path/$OldDbFile $text_files_path/$NewDbFile > $text_files_path/diffFile.txt"); 
exec($command);
```

it generate the new file in the specified folder but, it is empty!

Comment: You can write it using exec(); Check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I don't understand your question. `diff`, `grep` and `sed` are different tools with their own use/goal. What is it that you want to actually achieve?

Comment: @Oldskool I want use Diff to find differences between 2 text files and put the result in a new file. Then use grep and sed to do some condition on each line in the result text file.

Comment: @Oldskool I edit my question

Comment: @Ravindra Bhalothia see edit 1 please

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
    echo exec("sed -i -r 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt"); 
?>
```

Comment: I try this: $text_files_path = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/dbs"; $command = ("diff $text_files_path/$OldDbFile $text_files_path/$NewDbFile >  $text_files_path/diffFile.txt"); exec($command); it didn't work!